# returning character pointers from functions

Tags: c++

i obtained a double value with decimal part as 0 from calculations and then want to convert this value into char array consisting of the digits as elements(using ascii codes) and then return it...i wrote the following code for it...

```
char* as_string(double a,char* ptr)
{
  int digits=0;
  for(int i=1;;i++)
  {if(static_cast<int>(a/pow(10.0,i))==0)
  {digits=i;
  break;}
  }

 char b[digits];
 for(int i=digits-1;i>=0;i--)
 {
 b[digits-1-i]=static_cast<int>(a/pow(10.0,i))+48;
 a=a-((b[digits-1-i]-48)*pow(10.0,i));
 }

 strncpy(ptr,b,digits);
 return ptr;
}
```

everything went on all right...there was no syntax error but at runtime the prog was aboted each time...after some scrutiny i found that error is taking place around pointer ptr and strcpy statements(as the array b was successfully tested as filled with the digits )...can anyone plz. point out the error?

Comment: You didn't show us what argument you passed in to `ptr`.  Maybe it was null.

Comment: Oh God! Using `static_cast` doesn't make this 'C++'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ask yourself the Question:

**Is `ptr` pointing to a memory location big enough to hold `digits`?**
I don't think so.

The problem is you are passing a pointer `ptr` to the function but you don't know before hand how much memory is needed to be allocated to `ptr`.

You can have two options:

You can **guess** the maximum value possible allocate the same to `ptr` using `new` or on stack & then pass `ptr` to the function

Or

You allocate memory to `ptr` inside the function using `new` where you know exactly how much memory is needed. Note that to do so you will have to pass `ptr` as a  double pointer.

Comment: Not necessarily double pointer. We have references in C++. Best would be to pass a reference to pointer `char*&`

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: I agree, It is still a matter of choice though.

Comment: Absolutely. It's just that there are certain guidelines for choosing references vs. pointers for output parameters, and they say that a reference should be preferred if "null" value shouldn't be allowed, which in this case is the case. But indeed, it's a matter of choice and taste

Comment: @als u are right about the new concept...it solved my problem...but now there is another minor problem...i have inserted the line ptr=new char[digits] and copied b into it...now when i am running the code with say 43 and 10 any result which is less than 3 digits is being output with garbage characters appended to it such that the total no of digits become three...can u help?

Comment: @avinash: You are returning a `char*`, & probably you have code which is dislaying it to the standard output using `cout`. Since it is a `char*` It must be null terminated. `char*` treats all the content till it encounters a `\0` as string so you should add a `\0` after filling in the contents.

Comment: @als i did that...actually that was the first thing i did...ptr=new char[digits+1]...and after copying b,i reinforced ptr[digits+1]='\0'(although i didnt need to do this as strcpy automatically appends a null at last)...but even then the garbage character problem remained

Comment: @avinash: `strcpy` does not, `strncpy` does.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to re-invent the wheel.

Something like this should work just fine (note that I made it a `std::string` since you're using C++) :

```
std::string as_string(double a) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << a;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate enough memory for ptr to store the contents of b unless you've already done it before passing it in to your function (Since you take ptr as a second parameter).

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect that the pointer you pass to the function doesn't point to valid memory. 
For example, the following would result in undefined behavior (including but not limited to a crash).

```
char x;
as_string(0.232, &x); //UB
char y[too_small_size];
as_string(0.344, y); //UB
```

Answer (score 0):

- When you are returning the pointer back then you do not need to pass it, you can allocate some memory inside the function and simply return it.
- If you are sending the memory location through the pointer, then you might return the value, but check if the passed memory location is NULL or not. When calling make sure that it is a valid memory location.
- Always make sure that the memory block pointed to by the pointer is large enough, that is it has greater than `digits` no of location.